# Does sockets save any Data on HDD?

Tags: c#, c++, c, sockets

I have a question that might look strange but i arised in my mind.

I have made a small socket client-server chat application in C#. I wanted to know that does sockets save any data on the hard drive or they only use RAM?

If yes then is the case same for the C/C++ as well?

I mean for example, if I send some message from client to the server. Is it saved somewhere on the Hard-drive or it just exists there in the RAM only? I mean if OS is storing it somewhere or not?

I am sorry, if i asked a dumb question.

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RAM to wire then to RAM. No HDD involved. Yet, if the physical memory goes low, some memory pages containing data that came via the socket might be swapped out to disk. Other than that, no HDD is involved.

Comment: thanks, that cleared my doubt, I asked because I am trying to write a chat application that doesn't store anything on HDD. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Not a dumb question, but not one we can answer either.  It depends on the implementation and also how far down the stack you want to consider.  In general, I would not expect the network stack to save the data to the disk.  However, the OS might write it to disk as part of its virtual memory management (so, for example, if this is a security question, then yes it could end up on disk).

Answer (score 0):

It will not save in hard drive unless you implemented a serialization(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)  in your code. If you don't allocate memory in heap, using new operator in C++ or malloc or its family functions  if it is in case of C, it is not going to write anything in your heap. And while using heap it may access your hard drive memory but not mandatory. If you read following you may get a good idea on this memory manipulations in case of C/C++ prgrams
http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory